# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Here I have div with class `box-title` and I have `span` with related products and I want to change its text to  `'Choose Extra To make It More Special'` Why this error is coming please anyone can tell me.

```
function onloadCall()
{   
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('box-title');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        var div = divs[i];
        if(!div) break
        var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        if(span[0].innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
            span[0].innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', onloadCall, false);
```

Actually, my HTML tag is like this:

```
<div class="box-title"><strong><span>Related Products<span></strong></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined its giving this error

Comment: `div.getElementsByTagName('span')` probably returns an empty `NodeList`. It does not have a property `0`, hence `div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]` returns `undefined`. Then you try to access `span[0]` (property `0` of `undefined`) and that's where you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if(span[0].innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
    span[0].innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';
```

for:

```
if(span.innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
    span.innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';
```

And it should work.

Also, you can change the following:

```
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
```

For:

```
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

And leave the other code unchanged. If neither of this works, then make sure that there are any `span` tags in your html file.

Comment: Yes, but you are grabbing the first element of that array in the sentence: `var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];`

Comment: now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined error is comming after changing code to span[0] to span

Comment: Print the `span` variable content before the `if` sentence using either an `alert` or `console.log` like this:  `alert(span);`. Check that the *html* file contains `span` tags (paste the file content in the question if you can to further debug the problem)

Comment: actually my tag is ike this<div class="box-title"><strong><span>Related Products<span></strong></div> – geeta battin 2 mins ago edit

Comment: What the `alert` statement prints for you?

Comment: divs: NodeList[2]
0: <div>
firstChild: #text
firstElementChild: <strong>
innerHTML: "↵            <strong><span>Related Products</span></strong>↵        "
innerText: "Related Products↵"
isContentEditable: false
lastChild: #text
lastElementChild: <strong>
localName: "div"

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/) and it works, check that your `span` tag is properly closed

Comment: ya my span tag is closed properly i saw your demo its working

Comment: Thank you very much for me also working fine.once again thank you very much

Comment: please one more request i http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/14/ can you check this link i want to toggel paragraph depending on visibility of div with class name "box-collateral box-related"

Comment: I didn't understand what the script is suppose to do, but, I add some corrections on it, for example, the visibility test is working now, and the `div` iterations is working properly now (I rearranged the html to test the div inside div loop). Check it

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
if(span[0].innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
    span[0].innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';
```

I see you grabbing the first index of the array and then trying to grab the first index of that when it isn't an array.

**Try:**

```
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
if(span.innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
    span.innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';
```

Comment: after changing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined error is coming

Comment: Try flipping it around then: var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
if(span[0].innerHTML == 'Related Products') 
    span[0].innerHTML='Choose Extra To make It More Special';

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!div) {
    break;
}
var span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
if(span && span.innerHTML == 'Related Products') {
    span.innerHTML = 'Choose Extra To make It More Special';
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KfHVt/)

Comment: after pasting this code now i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined  error

Comment: @geetabattin Did you see that you said it for everybody ? Probably you have other error. You can see it working on my demo.

Comment: actually my tag is ike this<div class="box-title"><strong><span>Related Products<span></strong></div>